# how to use 'if i % number == 0:' with multiple numbers?

Tags: python, if-statement

just a quick question, how would i make it so that instead of just having 1 number (5 in this example) i could have multiple numbers (e.g. 5 or 6 or 7 etc.) or would i just have to do all of them seperately.

This is my example - `if (i % 5 == 0):`

i know it seems like a dumb question but i can't figure it out for some reason unless it's not possible. I've already tried `if (i % 5 or 6 == 0):` and `if i % (5 or 6) == 0:` but neither of them worked.

hope this makes sense
thank you in advance

Comment: you mean `if i % 5 == 0 or i % 6 == 0:` ?

Comment: No, you have to do it separately, if by that you mean `(i % 5 == 0) or (i % 6 == 0)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Comment: `if any(i % x == 0 for x in (5, 6))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'mod' function from numpy, which will return the result as a list. And put the result in the any function, which will return True if at least one value has a remainder after division.

[numpy.mod](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html)

```
import numpy as np

i = 10
aaa = np.any(np.mod(i, [1, 2, 3]))
print(aaa)
```

Output

```
True
```

Results  the remainder is zero everywhere.

```
i = 10
aaa = np.any(np.mod(i, [1, 2, 5]))
print(aaa)
```

Output

```
False
```